# Java Spring boot and Travis CI

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, travis-ci

I am trying to automatically run my test with Travis CI. I just can't find a good tutorial on how to do this in java. When I push to GitHub I keep getting the following error in Travis :

> The command "./mvnw clean install" exited with 127.

My .travis.yml file looks like this:

```
language: java
jdk:
  - openjdk11
script: ./mvnw clean install
```

This is my Test class

```java
package server;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@WebMvcTest(CoffeeController.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
class CoffeeControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void getAllCoffee() {
        try {
            mockMvc.perform(get("/coffee/all")).andExpect(status().isOk());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I searched several tutorials on Youtube and on the web but I can't seem to get the answer. I hope any of you can help me. I appreciate it very much! I also tried to remove the script but also no success.

Comment: Does the command work locally?
What exactly is the console output of travis?

Answer (score 1):

The return code 127 is telling you that it cannot find the command. In this case mvnw.

Please take a look, that your mvnw (mvn wrapper) is in the PATH, or try the absolute path. Also the mvnw should be part of the project, if it isn't pushed you can push it, or use a openjdk with mvn to build your app.

Comment: yea i removed mvnw. I now use   - mvn clean install. But I get the following error
The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/home/travis/build/koffieleut-backend). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory

Comment: So, where is your pom.xml with all the dependencies you need to build your application?

Comment: It is fixed, I Had to go into the projectname folder with : script : - cd projectname.
Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

It works for me:

```
sudo: required
language: java
before_install:
  - mvn clean install
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the script value to this:
script: ./mvn clean install

I'm not sure but you could try it